# mediaelement.js stop preloading in Opera

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am using the mediaelement.js audio player (through the mediaelement.js WordPress plugin). I noticed that it is automatically preloading songs when I visit a page with audio files. I would like to stop this as it will probably alarm some people to see the progress bar loading on several different players automatically. This only happens in Opera, not in IE or Chrome (didn't check Firefox). I browsed through the js file but couldn't find where to turn this off. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `preload="none"` to your audio tag

Comment: Attribute preload="none" it's just a hint to the browser; it may not obey it. Also preload is ignored if autoplay is on. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video and http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/audio/preload.html for more information